# In C#, Procedure that modifies the incoming array of doubles by normalizing?

Tags: c#

I've been trying to work on a solution towards the following problem:

Write a procedure that modifies the incoming array of doubles by normalizing it. Because this is a procedure, it will not return anything. Instead, I will have to modify the array directly, and because arrays are reference type variables, the array will be permanently changed even after this procedure. To normalize an array of numbers, simply divide each number by the maximum value in the array. So you will have to first find the largest number in the array, and then divide each number in the array by that number.

So far I haven't come with a clear solution to this particular, but I have written some code down.

```
public void Test9(double[] numbers)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
            {

            }
```

Comment: That's a start, but it is not much of an attempt yet. You need at least two loops - one to find the max, and one more to divide it out.

Comment: I am not quite sure how to approach this to be honest.

Comment: Seperate the problem into small sub-problem units. First problem: find the max value of your array. Second problem: Divide all array values by the value from problem 1. Breaking your (home)work into a series of shorter, simpler problems will make it exponentially easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
    static void Normalize(double[] numbers)
    {
        double max = numbers.Max();
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            numbers[i] = numbers[i] / max;
        }
    }
```

[.Net Fiddle Sample here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/D7rsHJ)

Answer (score 0):

public void Test9(double[] numbers)
        {

```
        //find the max 
        double max = numbers.Max();

        //nomarlize the numbers
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            numbers[i] = numbers[i] / max;
        }
```

}